# How to Draw Marker in MRI File With Respect to Contrast Agent

Tags: dicom

I am  really confuse over the draw overlay 
on MRI Image means its part is similar to Structure Report(SR) Processing or not

I am trying to read the MRI File in such way that from Contrast Agent. Also after so much searching on Google finally get some information such as

```
   "The data is extracted by injecting a contrast agent into a patient’s vein,then taking sequential snapshots of a volume of interest as the contrast agent diffuses through that area"
```

but i am totally new for this to help out can you help me for

```
  1. Give me specific link for these topic

  2. How to read the Contrast Agent value from MRI Dicom File.

  3. Also how to show a shaded region where the Cancer is detected or
     some kind of marker on that location where the pixel intensity of 
     dicom file is higher.
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, MRI scan is just a stack of grayscale images, pretty much as CT is, except that intensity units are of course different. So, just read it as any other dicom image, and look pixels values for intensities, or perform segmentation.
Cancer tumor regions and other features are stored in a separate dicom object, called RT structure set (it is produced usually by radiotherapy planning system or some contouring software).

Comment: dicom file modality value is SR also Media storage is "1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.88.22" of Enhanced SR SOP Class Name so where i find the RT Structure Set into this SR Modality

Comment: SR is structured report, I was talking about RTSTRUCT modality. The best way to find out what's in your SR file is to open it in some dicom viewer and observe the tags. You can use dcmtk to dump dicom files to XML, that makes them easy to analyse with a naked eye.

Comment: can you tell me the which tag is usefull in SR Modality to get Region of Interest

Comment: Have you opened your SR file in dicom viewer too see what tags contain roi coordinates?

Comment: @archine this is my SR dicom file plz download it from this link http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1365402449 plz where i find tag ROI

Comment: @user1556866 I do not see any ROIs in your SR dicom file. I would expect to see some ROI points, like in (3006, 0016) sequence or particularly like in (3006, 0050) ContourData tag.